# Add Div with attributes dynamically in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this below div which is kendo grid which i need to create it dynamically in JavaScript.

```html
<div kendo-grid id="tempGrid" hidden="hidden" k-options="meterGridOptions" k-rebind="columns"></div>
```

Comment: And where is your div?

Comment: Div needs to be placed in body.

Answer (score 0):

You can use template literal, `.insertAdjacentHTML()`

```js
var div = `<div kendo-grid id="tempGrid" hidden="hidden" k-options="meterGridOptions" k-rebind="columns">div</div>`;

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", div);
```

```html
<body></body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var m=document.getElementById('d1');
m.setAttribute("style","height:50%");
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `element.setAttributeNode(name, value)`

```js
var myDiv = document.createElement("div");
myDiv.setAttribute("kendo-grid", "");
myDiv.setAttribute("id", "tempGrid");
myDiv.setAttribute("hidden", "hidden");
myDiv.setAttribute("k-options", "meterGridOptions");
myDiv.setAttribute("k-rebind", "columns");

document.body.appendChild(myDiv)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had just removed the attribute `hidden` so that it will be visible.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var div = $("<div/>", {
    "id": "tempGrid",
    "k-options": "meterGridOptions",
    "k-rebind": "columns"
  }).text("Created via Jquery");

  div.attr("kendo-grid", "");
  div.appendTo(".container");
});
```

```css
.container {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">

</div>
```